# Outliner: Is there a way to select objects by data type within a Collection?

Tags: python, objects, interface, selection-tools, outliner

Is there a way to quickly select all objects of a given type *within a specific Collection*?

Right-clicking on a Collection in the **Outliner** brings up this menu:

[image]

<sup>↑ There is an option to "Select Objects" within the Collection.</sup>

There is also a way to select objects of the same type (as the selected one) using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in Object Mode:

[image]

Is there a way to select objects matching both criteria?

(In Collection AND of Type)

For that matter, a **logical AND** search that could match various combinations of these categories would be useful. (For other kinds of Boolean logic too.) It must at least be possible with Python, even if it's not so "quick" to pull up in the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can try:

1. Right click on the collection
2. Click select objects - it will select all objects in your collection
3. Press <kbd>/</kbd> to go to Local View (or View > Local View > Toggle Local View)
4. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and select objects by whateveryouwant
5. Press <kbd>/</kbd> again to exit Local View

Comment: Nice, thanks! (I made a minor edit to your answer, just that Isolation Mode is now listed as Local View in the menu)